# Error in Excel VBA function: "Object required"

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting an error while writing a function for excel. The purpose of the function is to look down the entire date column of a table and, for every match in that column, subtract the cost value (in the adjacent column) of that row from a total value. I have written a function in VBA, but I can't even start debugging it because I am stuck at the first error. The error says "Object required" and highlights the first line, but it seems like I am passing objects into the function already (Ranges). Here is my code.

```
Public Function WeeklyAllowance(firstCell As Range, lastCell As Range)
    Dim funds As Double
    Dim today As Date
    Dim thisWeekday As Integer
    Dim earlierDay As Date

    Set funds = 20
    today = Now()
    thisWeekday = Weekday(today)
    earlierDay = today - thisWeekday + 1 'This should be sunday at first

    Do Until earlierDay = today + 1 'Basically has one iteration for each day of the week until today
        Dim cell, column As Range
        Set column = Range(firstCell, lastCell)

        For Each cell In column     'Iterate through the cells in the column and check the dates
            If (cell.Value = earlierDay) Then
                Dim cellCol, cellRow As Integer
                cellCol = cell.column
                cellRow = cell.Row

                funds = funds - Sheet1.Cells(cellRow, cellCol + 1)
            End If

        Next cell

        earlierDay = earlierDay + 1 'Increment the day to check
    Loop

    WeeklyAllowance = funds
End Function
```

Could anyone help me with this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Set funds = 20` is the syntax used for objects. But you have above defined `funds` as a `double` (which is not an object type in `VBA`). Just remove the `Set` keyword:

`funds=20`

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim cell, column As Range
```

Wrong.

```
Dim cell As Range, column As Range
```

If your looping through days of the week then instead of adding 1 then use the dateadd function and parameter for weekdays.